# R add plots to a same axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created two Lists: List1 and List2. The elements of the lists are dataframes and using each 'n' element of the lists i create a plot:

```
fff= List1[[x]] %>% 
  gather(key, value, tmp117_corr, bme280_temp_corr) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(Time)) +
  #geom_col(data = DF_bar, aes(y = diff_a_b)) +
  geom_smooth(data = List2[[x]], aes(y = diff_a_b), method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "blue", linetype = "dashed") + # Add a red dashed trendline
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.4, 0.4)) +
  labs(title = location) +  # Add a title
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))  # Center the title
plot(fff)
```

here an example using n=1, n=2, n=3 and n=4:

[image]

now I would like to plot all this curves in one same axis, with n going from 1 to a big number. I have tried using a for-loop or a function but i am far away from a solution. A tip here would be very helpful

I dont provide a sample data because is too big but here the output of dput(head(List1[[x]],20)) and its the same for dput(head(List2[[x]],20)):

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1688162400, 1688166000, 1688169600, 
1688173200, 1688176800, 1688180400, 1688184000, 1688187600, 1688191200, 
1688194800, 1688198400, 1688202000, 1688205600, 1688209200, 1688212800, 
1688216400, 1688220000, 1688223600, 1688227200, 1688230800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin"), tmp117_corr = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), bme280_temp_corr = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to be reproducible?

Comment: (1) fyi, `tidyr::gather` was considered "retired" in Aug 2019, it has long been superseded by `pivot_longer`. While `gather` does all that you need here, I suggest shifting to the equivalent `pivot_longer(c(tmp117_corr, bme280_temp_corr), names_to="key", values_to="value")`. If/when your pivoting needs become slightly more nuanced, you need to pivot to something more than just "two columns", etc, then `pivot_longer` will do much more than `gather` can/will. (2) Sample data please, the output from `dput(head(List1[[1]],20))` (same for `List2`) should be a good start. Thanks!

Comment: How about binding the list into one dataframe and then using `facet_wrap` with `scales = "fixed"` to have all plots with the same axes. create df: `df <- bind_rows(List1, .id = "n")`. facet in ggplot: `... + facet_wrap(~n, scales = "fixed")`.

Comment: (1) Do you realize that `ggplot2` by default filters out `NA` data, since it cannot be plotted? With that, your sample data does not plot. Also, `! object 'diff_a_b' not found`, your `List1` and `List2` are _not_ the same. Similarly, `location` fails, but in our case (assuming `dplyr`), it fails because the only `location` found is `dplyr::location`, a function. (3) When I work around all of that and use random numbers in the two all-`NA` columns, it plots one facet. **Ultimately, your question is unfortunately not reproducible in several aspects.**